# Romanize generic Japanese in commandline

Tags: python, bash, transliteration, cjk

I would like to transliterate generic Japanese, including Kanji, by the standard [Hepburn system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepburn_romanization) on the bash command line.

I've evaluated several options, but

- Google Translator (available via Translate Shell) is only accurate at Hiragana / Katakana
- [KAKASI](http://kakasi.namazu.org) delivers ASCII, but no transliteration (so Toukyou instead of Tōkyō)

So I would like to parse the ouput of http://nihongo.j-talk.com
The output is in div.outputwrap or div.output

If it's futile to do this purely with Bash tools (curl / jq?), how could I reach this with Python / BeautifulSoup?

Sorry for giving no snippet, I have no clue how to POST data to a website AND use the result if there is no API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a look of source html of http://nihongo.j-talk.com site, I've made a guess of API.
Here are the steps:

1) Send a Japanese string to the server by wget and obtain the result in index.html.
2) Parse the index.html and extract Romaji strings.

Here is the sample code:

```
#!/bin/bash

string="日本語は、主に日本で使われている言語である。日本では法規によって「公用語」として規定されているわけではないが、各種法令（裁判所法第74条、会社計算規則第57条、特許法施行規則第2条など）において日本語を用いることが定められるなど事実>上の公用語となっており、学校教育の「国語」でも教えられる。"

uniqid="46a7e5f7e7c7d8a7d9636ecb077da485479b66bc"

wget -N --post-data "uniqid=$uiqid&Submit='Translate Now'&kanji_parts=standard&kanji=$string&converter=spaced&kana_output=romaji" http://nihongo.j-talk.com/ > /dev/null 2>&1 

perl -e ' 
$file = "index.html"; 
open(FH, $file) or die "$file: $!\n";

while (<FH>) {
    if (/<div id=.spaced. class=.romaji.>(.+)/) {
        ($str = $1) =~ s/<.*?>//g;
        $str =~ s/\&\#(\d+);/&utfconv($1)/eg;
        print $str, "\n";
    }
}

# utf16 to utf8
sub utfconv {
    $utf16 = shift;
    my $upper = ($utf16 >> 6) & 0b0001_1111 | 0b1100_0000;
    my $lower = $utf16 & 0b0011_1111 | 0b1000_0000;
    pack("C2", $upper, $lower);
}'
```

Some comments:
- I wrote the parser with Perl just because it is rather familiar to me but you may modify or convert it to other language by reading index.html file.
- The uniqid string is what I have picked from html source of the site.  If it doesn't work well, make sure what is embedded in the html source.

Hope this helps.